# Is there a word for the feeling of growing old?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the feeling of growing old? Or the feeling of becoming more mature?

Something that describes the way you feel when you wake up in the morning and notice how much has changed:

> When the man woke up, he saw his wife, his daughter in the crib, and finally, himself in the mirror, and felt [feeling] as he pondered how fast time had gone by.

It's not really yearning for the past, though, so it's not quite nostalgia. It's a bit more like the way someone would feel when they say: "the days are long but the years are short."

Comment: Hi Jordan, welcome to English Language & Usage. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The process of growing old from either an internal perspective (i.e. your own), or external perspective (in the eyes of others) is known as **senescence**.

From [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/senescence?r=66):

> #### senescence
>
> growing old; aging

Or, a more colorful and richer definition from [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/senescence) which aligns with the feelings you describe in your question:

> #### senescence
>
> *Do your stiff knees make it harder and harder to get out of that cozy chair? It may be that senescence is at work, meaning you’re getting older.*
>
> *Senescence* is a fancy way to describe **the process of aging**. If you don’t want to admit straight out that old age made you lose that tango contest, blame it on senescence — it sounds mysterious and exciting. Senescence is sometimes used in a scientific context to describe cells in your body that can no longer grow and divide, which can affect your ability to dance like you did when you were 20.

Comment: Quibble:  Is senescence a feeling?

Comment: @ab2 Plenty of hits for *feeling of senescence* in Google Books. Here’s the first: *our body begins a deeper conversation with time and **the feeling of senescence** seeks our attention and awareness. We realize that one day we will be a memory.*. From [*The Challenges of Aging | Brian Alger On the Liminal Frontiers of Experience*](http://brianalger.com/challenges-of-aging/).

Answer (score 0):

I like **ageing** to describe this feeling.  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ageing)

> the organic process of growing older and showing the effects of
>   increasing age

As in:

I need help to cope with the demands of my **ageing** body.